# generate sequential number using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has 200 records. The columns in the table are

Client_id, Name, age, dob

sample data:

[image]

Now I have a select statement that needs to generate sequential number but not from the table.

So my select statement is:

select row_number, client_id, name
from #temp1....

I don't want to get the number from the #temp1 table rather I want to generate dynamically on the fly.

any help?!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? (Or something completely different?) You tagged both, maybe by accident?

Comment: I am using SQL server. Tagged my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `row_number()`. For example:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY client_id) row_number,
       client_id,
       name
       FROM #temp1;
```

Possibly change the `ORDER BY` clause, if you don't want the numbers to be ordered by the client ID.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.